# Rails ActiveRecord Association issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've 2 model:

Performance and PerformanceType and 2 respective tables: performances and performance_types.

Into performances there is a foreign key column "performance_type_id".

How I can get the name of performance_type_id from the other table using ActiveRecord Associations?

```
class Performance < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :users
has_one :rates
has_one :performace_types
end

class PerformanceType < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :performances
end
```

With above code I try to do into console:

```
myvar = Performance.first
myvar.performance_types
NoMethodError: undefined method `performance_types' for #<Performance:0x007f9694b3e700>
```

I know that the problem is for my bad interpretation of active record associations, can anyone help me?

regards.

migrations from creating to foreign keys adding...

```
class CreatePerformances < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :performances do |t|

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreatePerformanceTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :performance_types do |t|

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class AddPerformanceTypeIdToPerformance < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :performances, :performance_type_id, :integer
  end
end

class AddAppointmentInfoToPerformance < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :performances, :user_id, :integer
    add_column :performances, :start_at, :datetime
    add_column :performances, :end_at, :datetime
  end
end

class AddUserToPerformances < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_foreign_key :performances, :users
  end
end

class AddTypeToPerformances < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_foreign_key :performances, :performance_types
  end
end

class AddAdditionalFieldsToPerformanceType < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :performance_types, :name, :string
    add_column :performance_types, :description, :string
  end
end

class AddPerformanceTypeToRate < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_foreign_key :rates, :performance_types
  end
end

class AddRateToPerformances < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :performances, :rate_id, :integer
    add_foreign_key :performances, :rates
  end
end
```

Comment: It should be singular, not plural.  `has_one :performance_type`  You've also misspelt performance - might be just when typing your question though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is what you want.  The foreign key performance_type_id remains in performances.  You have many performances with the same performance type, but each performance has only one performance type.

```
class Performance < ActiveRecord::Base 
  # note performance type is singular
  belongs_to :performance_type
end

class PerformanceType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :performances 
end

p = Performance.first
# this should work 
p.performance_type
```

Comment: Doesn't work

NoMethodError: undefined method `performance_type' for #<Performance:0x007fcf75a893b8>

Answer (score 4):

`has_one` and `belongs_to` refer to a single object so you should use singularized form

```
class Performance < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :users
    has_one :rates
    has_one :performance_type
end

class PerformanceType < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :performance
end
```

Comment: Not sure why this answer is being upvoted; the has_one associations are still plural, the "has_one :perfomace_type" is misspelled, and there is no mention of the migration files (so how do we know he actually setup the association the correct way?)

Answer (score 0):

You should change your Performance class listing the "has_one" relationship with the singular model (not plural):

```
class Performance < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user
  has_one :rate
  has_one :performance_type
end

class PerformanceType < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :performance
end
```

It's also important that your migration file is correctly configured, too:

```
class CreatePerformances < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :performances do |t|
    end

    create_table :performance_types do |t|
      t.belongs_to :performance, index: true
      t.belongs_to :rate
      t.belongs_to :user
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok, now the associations are in singular form...

The tables are or because I have correctly created the FK to the 3 tables.

Now how access to performance_types column with ruby notation?

Comment: Ehm, doesnt work.

How access to other columns by the association?

Comment: Can you post your migration file?

Comment: Whoa, OK. Looks like you've been doing a lot of migrations for this. It's a bit hard for me to follow. Could you post your `schema.rb` file?

Comment: @Tommyixi do your research, what you are saying is WRONG. `has_one` association are singular. downvoted.

Comment: OK. @Cyzanfar research completed: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association Read up and then give me my upvote back. Thanks.

Comment: as per the link you provided. Look at the association name it's `account` and not `accounts`. It's a common mistake for people new to rails. no worries but the downvote will remain

Comment: What are you referring to? I've used the singular (performance_type) in my model. When there is a `has_one` association you use the singular (which I have in my models). When there is a `belongs_to` you also use the singular. What specifically in my code is incorrect? @Cyzanfar